# join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'

Tags: python, html, django

Проблема: при открытии любой из категорий у меня ошибка которая в заголовке.
У меня есть страница с категориями:

```
    <ul class="list-group">
                <a style="margin-bottom: 20px" href="{% url 'incateg' 'electronics' %}"><li class="list-group-item">Electronics</li></a>
                <a style="margin-bottom: 20px" href="{% url 'incateg' 'cars' %}"><li class="list-group-item">Cars</li></a>
                <a style="margin-bottom: 20px" href="{% url 'incateg' 'sports' %}"><li class="list-group-item">Sports</li></a>
                <a style="margin-bottom: 20px" href="{% url 'incateg' 'food' %}"><li class="list-group-item">Food</li></a>
                <a style="margin-bottom: 20px" href="{% url 'incateg' 'accessories' %}"><li class="list-group-item">Accessories</li></a>
                <a style="margin-bottom: 20px" href="{% url 'incateg' 'books' %}"><li class="list-group-item">Books</li></a>
    </ul>
```

Функция:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def categor(request, cat):
    cat_list = Listing.objects.filter(category=cat)
    empty = False
    if len(cat_list) == 0:
        empty: True
    return render("auctions/incateg.html", {
        "cat": cat,
        "empty": empty,
        "items": cat_list
    })
```

И цикл в incateg.html который должен показать все итемы в категории которая открыта:

```
{% for item in items_list reversed %}
          {% if item.categor == cat %}
          {% endif %}
            {% if empty %}
                <p>There is no avaliable listings in this category</p>
            {% endif }
{% endfor %}
```

[image: скрин ошибки]

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки с полным стектрейсом.

Comment: TypeError at /incateg/electronics

join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/incateg/electronics
Django Version:  3.1.7
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'

Exception Location:  C:\Users\go1x1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\genericpath.py, line 152, in _check_arg_types
Python Executable:  C:\Users\go1x1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

Comment: Python Version:  3.9.1
Python Path:  

['D:\\cs50\\commerce',
 'C:\\Users\\go1x1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\go1x1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\go1x1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\go1x1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\go1x1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\go1x1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:  Mon, 28 Jun 2021 10:19:26 +0000

Comment: Добавьте в сам вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: я добавил context и теперь - render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template_name'

Comment: Все работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым параметром в render должен передаваться request, вторым - путь к шаблону, третьим - данные (контекст), см. [документацию](https://djangodoc.ru/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/). Вы `request` не передаете, получается путь к шаблону передается вместо request, а данные для шаблона вместо пути шаблона.

Другие проблемы в коде, которые я вижу:

- В словаре есть ключ `items`, но нет `items_list`, который указан в шаблоне.
- `empty: True` никак не модифицирует переменной `empty`, нужно заменить на присваивание `empty = True`.
- У объектов в вашем списке, насколько я понимаю, есть поле `category` (судя по имени параметра, используемому при фильтрации), а в шаблоне проверяется поле `categor`.
- По логике проверять значение `empty` в шаблоне нужно вне цикла, т.е. сделать, чтобы for был вложен в if, а не наоборот (как сейчас). Сейчас у вас при пустом списке for ни разу не выполнится, и `<p>There is no avaliable listings in this category</p>` не отобразится.

Comment: <p>There is no avaliable listings in this category</p> отобразилось много раз, я убрал эту строку

Comment: Много раз отобразилось именно потому что в цикл вложено. Почему условие `if empty` выполнилось, хотя в empty True должно быть только если список пустой - это уже другой вопрос)